In AWS, how to find the SAML assumed IAM roles current sessions for all users?
In our AWS accounts we use an Identity Provider to log in (console, cli) with IAM Roles (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers.html). We have federated IAM Roles like Developer, ReadOnly, FullAdmin. I mention that it is only human operators (not other AWS services) that use these roles. 
From the IAM Role Trusted Entities:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::[aws-account-id]:saml-provider/[idp-name]"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithSAML"
        }
    ]
}

My questions:

I would like to find/see at a given moment (current or past) the IDP users who assumed a specific IAM role (for example ReadOnly). The command aws sts get-caller-identity shows only the information of my session:

aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "UserId": "AROAVZJJ5J7KYGVGP3XAG:x.y@mail.com",
    "Account": "[aws-account-id]",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::[aws-account-id]:assumed-role/ReadOnly/x.y@mail.com"
}


Which event name in CloudTrail could I use to find this information?
Thank you.

